# Chrome Dev Tools no longer lets me position to bottom

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-developer-toolbar

Google Chrome dev tools no longer lets me re-position it to the bottom of the page instead of the right side. Anyone know how I can re-enable this function? It makes it very difficult to use it in certain screen layouts.

I'm using Chrome v 33.0.1750.154 m
Windows 8.1

Interestingly, the opposite is true in Canary(v 35.0.1900.0 canary). In canary dev tools are stuck on the bottom and can't be re-positioned to the side.

Is there some check-box I accidentally clicked or what??
Currently I can only dock or un-dock the dev tools panel, but the option to change it's position inside the window is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click and hold the dock/undock button you get the option to reposition.

Comment: This was not intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Cmd-Shift-D also works, as I just found out